# boosted download speed in firefox

Tags: firefox, download

Why is it that when you leave a save dialog box open(When you click on a link that links to a downloadable file and opens a dialog box that lets you choose what location you will save the file). Why is that when you leave that dialog box open for let's say 30 minutes. And when you click the save file button. It would already have downloaded almost 20mb, in my case(745 kbps).
What is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, You can't boost your download speed in firefox . The real reason is that Firefox already downloads when you try to save it in a location . It's the same as modern downloader these days .

Have you tried IDM ? 
You think, how can they can do view contents before you download but they don't download it ?

:)

Comment: Is their an IDM that is available for the latest release of firefox?

Comment: yup . There is :) It supports a lot of browsers  :) 
Almost the popular browsers I mean :)

Answer (score 6):

The speed isn't actually boosted, Firefox just starts downloading the file as soon as the dialog opens.

I actually like this design as I don't usually open a save dialog for files that I don't want to save -- this just makes starting the download even faster since the browser is already working while you are typing in a name for the file or searching for the directory to save it in. Quite convenient.

Comment: I believe it's also to make the security part of it ("OK" not being clickable for a moment) much more tolerable.